# TypeError at /admin/auth/user/add/ save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: python, django

I use signals.py to create a profile object when a user object is created. This used to work before but it does not work any more whether I use my code or I use admin panel to create a user.

Code for creating a Profile object is as follows:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

If I comment this signals.py the error (when I add a User) goes away, bypassing creation of a Profile object when a User is created.

Profile clasa has this code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pictures')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        image = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if image.height>300 or image.width>300:
            size = (300, 300)
            image.thumbnail(size)
            image.save(self.image.path)
```

I use Windows 7 with Python 3.7.9 using db.sqlite3 . HELP!!